# Using ES6 classes OR Object Literals in controllers for an Express + NodeJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

There are 2 things that I'm very confused about.

1. What is the advantage of using any of ES6 class or Object literals.
2. And where should I use any of them?

Some of the examples that I'm trying out are mentioned below. Please let me know when to use particular way of implementation and when not to.

Class Example 1:

```
// auth.js
class Auth {
  login(req, res) {...}
  signup(req, res) {...}
}

module.exports = new Auth();

// index.js
const auth = require('auth');
```

Class Example 2:

```
// auth.js
class Auth {
  login(req, res) {...}
  signup(req, res) {...}
}

module.exports = Auth;

// index.js
const Auth = require('auth');
const auth = new Auth();
```

Object Literal Example:

```
// auth.js
module.exports = {
  login: (req, res) => {...},
  signup: (req, res) => {...}
};

// index.js
const auth = require('auth');
```

What I think from reading about them is that:

**Class Example 1:**

- You can not create more than 1 object. Because a module is only executed once. So, on every import you will get the same object. Something similar to singleton. (Correct me here if I misunderstood it)
- You will not be able to access the static methods of the class because you are only exporting the object of the class.

**Class Example 2:**

- If you have a class that contains nothing but helper methods and the object does not have any state, It makes no sense creating object of this class all the time. So, in case of helper classes, this should not be used.

**Object Literal Example:**

- You can not do inheritance.
- Same object will be passed around on every require. (Correct me if I'm wrong here as well)

Please help me understand these concepts, what I'm missing out, what I've misunderstood and what should be used when and where. I'll be very grateful for your help.

**Feel free to edit the question, if you think I made a mistake somewhere.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Class Example 1: You can not create more than 1 object. Because a module is only executed once. So, on every import you will get the same object. Something similar to singleton.

Correct. This is an antipattern therefore. Do not use it. `class` syntax is no replacement for object literals.

> You will not be able to access the static methods of the class because you are only exporting the object of the class.

Theoretically you can do `auth.constructor.…` but that's no good.

> Class Example 2: If you have a class that contains nothing but helper methods and the object does not have any state, It makes no sense creating object of this class all the time. So, in case of helper classes, this should not be used.

Correct. Use a simple object literal instead, or even better: multiple named exports instead of "utility objects".

> Object Literal Example: You can not do inheritance.

You still can use `Object.create` to do inheritance, or parasitic inheritance, or really anything.

> Same object will be passed around on every require.

Correct, but that's not a disadvantage. If your object contains state, you should've used a `class` instead.

Comment: Okay, great! I was thinking that classes are kind of replacement for object literals. Is that no true then? And is it okay to have mix of both classes and object literals throughout your project (Controllers using object literals and some Services that holds state using classes)? Thanks.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it clarifies almost all of my doubts. Thanks :)

Comment: No, `class` syntax is a replacement for constructor declarations + prototypes. You should only use them when they carry state / you need multiple instances. You can and should mix them with objects, use whatever is appropriate. Notice that object literal syntax was enhanced with concise methods and computed properties as well in ES6.

Comment: @Bergi 'multiple named exports instead of "utility objects"', what is the advantage of using this? if I have a single `utils.js` where I store let's say 20 small functions I need, is it not easier and more maintainable to just import the whole utils.js in any file where I need some of those functions? So I can always move stuff around/refactor and my `utils.anyMethod();` will always be defined?

Comment: @Mirko The advantages are simpler declarations, more flexibility on importing, the ability to tree-shake when bundling, better perf with native module support, and a few more. And yes, you still can do `import *  as utils from "utils.j"` and use them exactly as `utils.anyMethod()`. There's never a reason to default-export an object.

Answer (score 0):

If your class has got a constructor, you can build several objects from this class threw :

```
var Panier= require('./panier');    
var panier1 = new Panier(13, 12, 25);
var panier2 = new Panier(1, 32, 569);
```

Of course your Panier would be defined in the file Panier.js located in the same directory :

```
module.exports = class Panier
{
    constructor(code, qte, prix)
    {
        this.codeArticle = code;
        this.qteArticle = qte;
        this.prixArticle = prix;
    }
    getCode()
    {
        return this.codeArticle;
    }
    getQte()
    {
        return this.qteArticle;
    }
    getPrix()
    {
        return this.prixArticle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can obviously do that. What I want to know is when and where to use the 3 scenarios and what are the advantages/disadvantages of one over other.