# Javascript export class or object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the best practice for exporting?

```
class MyUtils {
  print() {...}
  convert() {...}
}
export default new MyUtils();
```

Or:

```
const myUtils = {
  print() {...}
  convert() {...}
}
export default myUtils;
```

Or something else?

**Note: this should be a singleton, no more than 1 instance**

Comment: you can do the following for classes: `export default class MyUtils {}`

Comment: Do you intend on having a single instance of the Object or a new instance per use?

Comment: updated my question, this should be a singleton

Comment: Basically your question is what the best way is to create a single object.      What do you think? How do you usually create a single object? :)

Comment: Duplicate of [Using ES6 classes OR Object Literals in controllers for an Express + NodeJS app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37895664/218196)

Comment: @Vic can you please paste the actual methods here. I highly doubt your need to have `print` and `convert` be instance methods

Comment: @naomik they are just examples, call it whatever you want

Comment: @Vic my point is that people can help you more effectively if you paste actual code. Precision matters a great deal when it comes to expressing code. I'm not "calling it whatever I want"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second option should work for the singleton and that is what I use normally. From Felix's comment, I get that modules are singleton's and option 1 would also work. I am still inclined to go with the second option since the code makes my intention to use singleton very clear.

```
const myUtils = {
  print() {...}
  convert() {...}
}

export default myUtils;
```

Comment: Does the first option create a new object each time though? I added a `constructor` with `console.log` and imported it in multiple files and it only printed once?

Comment: @Vic: Modules are only evaluated once.

Answer (score 2):

Generally exporting an object as the default export is a bit of an antipattern. Your very best option would be to do

```
export function print() {...}
export function convert() {...}
```

then do

```
import * as utils from "./utils";
```

to avoid creating the object entirely, and rely on the module object itself to act as your namespace.

Answer (score -2):

If it's a singleton, just export the object. You should export the class like below, and only if you're using it more than once. (The point of a class after  all is that it should function like a template for creating multiple objects)

```
export default class MyUtils {
  print() {...}
  convert() {...}
}
```